# How to get the GMSMarker which are inside the GMSPolygon

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am using google maps api to draw a polygon into the map in my ios app, I achieved this free hand drawing polygon from this link :
https://github.com/saru2020/SARMapDrawView
So now i have a GMSPolygon but i want get the GMSMarker which lies inside the polygon.
If we want to get the markers which are in the screen we do it like this way: [Google Maps for iOS - How can you tell if a marker is within the bounds of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065098/google-maps-for-ios-how-can-you-tell-if-a-marker-is-within-the-bounds-of-the-s) 
so i was wondering if there is any way to get only the marker which are inside the polygon.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031919/how-to-calculate-number-of-markers-inside-a-polygon-in-google-maps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah this way can be done, but i was thinking if google map api for ios has any method which gives markers which are inside the polygon.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I use this.

```
if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(marker.position, polygonPath, true){
   //marker is within the polygon based on the polygon.path 
}
```